# Reverse List Order in Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

How do I modify this code so that it adds each new object to the top of the list instead of the bottom? I would like the latest object to be added to the very top of the list so you see older objects as you scroll lower down on the list.

```
public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

public StatusAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> status) {
    super(context, R.layout.homepage, status);
    mContext = context;
    mStatus = status;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.homepage, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.usernameHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.usernameHP);
        holder.statusHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.statusHP);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    ParseObject statusObject = (ParseObject)mStatus.get(position);

    // title
    String username = statusObject.getString("newUser") + ":";
    holder.usernameHomepage.setText(username);

    // content
    String status = statusObject.getString("newStatus");
    holder.statusHomepage.setText(status);

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView usernameHomepage;
    TextView statusHomepage;

}

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to display list in reverse order newest item on top then just reverse your list.Java collection class provide a reverse method which reverse all items in a list.See below code -

`Collections.reverse(aList);`

Above code reverse list item and store result in same list.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

Every concrete implementation of the `List` interface defines `void add(int index, E element)`

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list
>   (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position
>   (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
>   indices).

So, you can `add(0,item)` and then notify that your data set has changed. This will make your newly added item appear at the top rather than at the bottom.

Comment: ...or just adapter.insert(item,0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method to reverse your list order, I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
private List<ParseObject> reverseListOrder(List<ParseObject> status)
{
    Iterator<ParseObject> it = status.iterator();
    List<ParseObject> destination = new ArrayList<>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        destination.add(0, it.next());
        it.remove();
    }
    return destination;
}
```

And no need to change anything in your StatusAdapter class, call above function where you are initializing StatusAdapter.

> **Usage:**

```
StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(this, R.layout.item, reverseListOrder(listOfStatus));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list you are passing to the adapter in the same order as you like to see the items in the list.

```
public static void sort (List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

[Ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E))